# Randomly Select Point in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have generated 1000 random points ranging from 0 to 500. I would like to randomly select one point and then predict the probability of selecting that point. Could someone please help?

Comment: To answer exactly, we need to know something about the probability distribution used to generate the points. For example, if it is continuous, then the answer is simple: any point has probability measure zero. Or are you after an answer obtained via simulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume your random points are stored in a vector x:

```
 x=500*rand(1,1000);
```

The probability of selecting any single point in that set of random numbers is exactly 1/1000. So you don't need to compute that.

To select a random item just use something like this:

```
choice = x(randi([1,1000],1))
```

where randi just returns a random integer in the [1,1000] interval.

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate a random number and take its `mod` with `501`, the result
   range will be 0-500, select the point from the index of your random
   number.
2. To calculate the probability of selecting a specific point repeat step (1) n times and check how many times your point has been selected, its probability will be :

   [image]

for `i` : point index, and `j` : trial index ...